# celery periodic tasks not executing

Tags: python, django, celery

I am learning celery and I created a project to test my configuration. I installed `celery==4.0.0` and `django-celery-beat==1.0.1` according to the latest documentation.

In drf_project(main project dir with manage.py)/drf_project/celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'drf_project.settings')
app = Celery('drf_project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

In drf_project/drf_project/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ('django_celery_beat',)
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "test_1": {
        "task": "tasks.print_test",
        "schedule": timedelta(seconds=2),
    },
}
```

In drf_project/drf_project/**init**.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

In my user_management app (drf_project/user_mangement/) I added a tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery
from time import strftime

app = Celery()

@app.task
def print_test():
    print strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    with open('abc.txt', 'ab+') as test_file:
        test_file.writeline(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

when i run the celery worker and my django project dev server in different terminals by:

```
 celery -A drf_project worker -l info
```

and

```
 python manage.py runserver
```

I can see my task in celery log like:

```
[tasks]
   . user_management.tasks.print_test
```

But it is not executing. Also I am not getting any error. SO what I am doing wrong? I followed the official documentation of celery.

Comment: What is the solution?? I'm also facing same problem

Comment: Check the marked answer.. The docs says that you have run the scheduler separately.

Answer (score 35):

For running periodic tasks you have to run two services: **celery beat** together with **celery worker**.

You can find more information at the bottom of [following](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) page.

Comment: I started the beat service by `celery -A drf_project beat`. But still the task is not getting executed and I cant see some kind of log anywhere in django server and celery .

Comment: It took me days to find out. the beat is just sending tasks when they are due. And those tasks are queuing there. So, you have to start at least a worker so that those tasks are picked and executed!

Comment: @ManishGupta Can you update your answer based on DatTT 's comment

Comment: @DaTT, you just saved me days. ;)

Comment: The short answer is to just add `-B` to your celery worker command, e.g. `celery -A proj worker -B`. This isn't recommended for production but it's a nice quick way to get beat running.

Comment: Thanks! ANother thing is running both of them on production. On development you just open another tab but on prod you need services and daemon

Answer (score 0):

Here is the docker-compose file configuration that I have set up to run celery worker and celery beat. It does the job. Make sure you change main_project_folder name in the `docker-compose` file below:

```
version: '3'

services:
  
  redis:
    image: "redis:latest"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: madefire/chordtest
    command: bash -c "celery -A main_project_folder_name worker -l INFO"
    environment:
      - BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
      - C_FORCE_ROOT=true
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/
    depends_on:
      - redis

  celery_beat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: madefire/chordtest
    command: bash -c "celery -A main_project_folder_name beat"
    environment:
      - BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
      - C_FORCE_ROOT=true
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/
    depends_on:
      - redis
```