# django celery Received unregistered task of type 'print_test'

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

In continuity with the question: [celery periodic tasks not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839324/celery-periodic-tasks-not-executing)

I have set up django with celery like:

drf_project/drf_project/celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'drf_project.settings')
app = Celery('drf_project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

In drf_project/drf_project/init.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

drf_project/user_management/tasks.py

```
from drf_project.celery import app
from time import strftime

@app.task
def print_test():
    print strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    with open('abc.txt', 'ab+') as test_file:
        test_file.writeline(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

In drf_project/drf_project/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ('django_celery_beat',)
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "test_1": {
        "task": "tasks.print_test",
        "schedule": timedelta(seconds=2),
    },
}
```

I ran both celery worker and beat in different terminals with commands:

```
celery -A drf_project worker -l info -E
```

and

```
celery -A drf_project beat -l info -S django
```

The beat is sending tasks to worker every 2 seconds like:

> [2016-11-28 12:25:19,314: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task Importing contacts (print_test)

But the worker throws the error like:

> [2016-11-28 12:24:57,551: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'print_test'.
>   The message has been ignored and discarded.
>
> Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
>   Or maybe you're using relative imports?
>
> Please see
>   http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
>   for more information.
>
> The full contents of the message body was:
>   u'[[], {}, {"chord": null, "callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null}]' (77b)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 549, in on_task_received
>       strategy = strategies[type_]
>   KeyError: 'print_test'

I can see the task in my worker app like:

```
[tasks]
  . user_management.tasks.print_test
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting in the CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE the absolute path of the task, "user_management.tasks.print_test"

It should look like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ('django_celery_beat',)
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "test_1": {
        "task": "user_management.tasks.print_test",
        "schedule": timedelta(seconds=2),
    },
}
```

Comment: I have tried everything. from `"user_management.tasks.print_test"` to `"drf_project.user_management.tasks.print_test"`. If i use any of these 2 options I cant see my task listed in worker. It only shows up in worker if I choose `tasks.print_test`

Comment: In CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE, the task must be called as it appears in the celery tasks list.

Comment: Try listing all the tasks and searching yours, >>> from proj.celery import app
>>> app.tasks
{'celery.chord_unlock':
    <@task: celery.chord_unlock>,
 'celery.backend_cleanup':
    <@task: celery.backend_cleanup>,
 'celery.chord':
    <@task: celery.chord>}

Comment: I cant see my task in app.tasks

Comment: Try using 'code'celery -A {celery_app_name} inspect registered'code' This should return you all registered tasks.

Comment: It throw error:  Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.

Comment: Ok I can see my task like `{u'celery@Anil': [u'user_management.tasks.print_test']}`